# X509Certificate.Import file from folder on disk

Tags: x509certificate

Is it possible to import a certificate file using a (relative) path? I am trying to follow the example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te7383x5.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

```
        cert.Import(  relative path )
```

I am not having any success. Keep running into "file not found" exception.

Is a fully-qualified path required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Win32 documentation discourages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) use of relative paths so use of the absolute path is strongly recommended.